# Swift gives a nil error while the values is filled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Hello I have a ViewController in my project where I calculate some stuff with GPS etc. After i'm done I use the prepareForSegue function to pass the variables to the next ViewController. Therefore I put my current String variables into two text fields in the next VC.

```
println("\(startloc!) and \(endloc!)")
destination.startaddress.text = startloc!
destination.destinationaddress.text = endloc!
```

Somehow they keep giving nil. The println shows me that they are filled with the right value. What could be wrong and what to do?

Answer (score 1):

> I use the prepareForSegue function to pass the variables to the next ViewController. Therefore I put my current String variables into two text fields in the next VC.

That's your problem. At the time of `prepareForSegue`, the text fields in the next view controller do not exist. Thus, they are nil — and you crash when you try to assign to their `text`.

Comment: Ah I see. How can I solve this? Should I create new variables and pass it to the variables?

Comment: See my answer in the linked duplicate.